# How to create N copies of a label inside .map function of tf.data

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have the following functions to read audio files along with their labels using `tf.data`

```
def get_waveform(file_path):
    audio_binary = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
    waveform, sr = tf.audio.decode_wav(contents=audio_binary,
                                       desired_channels=1)
    waveform = tf.squeeze(waveform, axis=-1)
    frames = tf.signal.frame(waveform, sr * 3, (sr * 3) // 2, pad_end=True)
    return frames


def get_label(file_path):
    parts = tf.strings.split(
        input=file_path,
        sep=os.path.sep)
    return parts[-2]

def get_waveform_and_label(file_path):
  label = get_label(file_path)
  waveform = get_waveform(file_path)
  label = ???
  return waveform, label
```

The `get_waveform` function will return N frames of a waveform for a single audio file and all frames will have the same label. So how can I repeat it N times and return it by zipping frames and their corresponding labels?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a `tf.map_fn` function to repeat the label. It takes a function and tensor as input and applies the function to every element in the tensor. So the idea is to first use the `tf.shape` function to get the shape of the waveform tensor and then pass that to the `tf.map_fn` function as the second argument to specify the number of times to repeat the label.

```
def get_waveform_and_label(file_path):
  label = get_label(file_path)
  waveform = get_waveform(file_path)
  label = tf.map_fn(lambda x: label, tf.shape(waveform))
  return waveform, label
```